# RegExp Boundary is not considering letters after Special Characters

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

**Requirement:**

I need to get the searched word in a sentence. So am using ***RegExp Word Boundary*** for that.

***Note:** I need to match WHOLE WORD.*

**The issue am facing:**

When I use RegExp Word Boundary to search a word in a sentence, it's not considering the letters after special character. For example, the below string has only 1 Greek but the RegExp is saying that it has 2.

```
"The particularly mysteries, which honored the Greek's goddess Demeter Greek."
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
word: string = "Greek";
sentence: string = "The particularly mysteries, which honored the Greek's goddess Demeter Greek.";
isWordThere: boolean = false;
searchedValue: any = [];

constructor() {
    const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + this.word + '\\b', 'g');
    this.isWordThere = regex.test(this.sentence);
    this.searchedValue = this.sentence.match(regex);
    console.log(this.searchedValue);
}
```

What changes I can do to match the whole word? or what else I can do to achieve the requirement?

Comment: First, do not reuse the regex with `g`, the first call to `.text` moves the regex index. For test, use the regex without `g`. If you mean there should be no `'s` after word, use `new RegExp('\\b' + this.word + "\\b(?!'s\\b)")`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for the suggestion. Now its not considering the Greek's if I search for Greek but if I just search for Gr then its returning the result but it shouldn't. The requirement is to match the complete word.

Comment: Tokenizing  natural languages is a complex problem and cannot be solved with regexes alone. Start by defining a "word", for example, which of the following are "words": `Peter's  readers' rock'n'roll AT&T nitty-gritty N/A`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of \b which is a special kind of non-capturing group, you will want a general negative lookahead (and you might as well include the same thing in a negative look behind)

```
    RegExp('(?<![a-z''])' + this.word + '(?![a-z'']', 'gi')
```

This assumes your 'words' are only alphas.  I also changed it to ignore case and match either Greek or greek.  This will not match Greek's or Greeks or fenugreek.  It will match Greek and greek-specific.  If you change the example to search for "all" in the sentence "Y'all should not take all the cookies." it won't match the Y'all but will match the all.

Comment: Thank you for your response. With few modification to your answer, am able to achieve my requirement. +1.

Answer (score 1):

With few modifications to @chris-maurer's answer, Am able to achieve my requirement and the correct RegExp is as shown below.

```
RegExp("(?<![-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿœēčŭ])" + this.word + "(?![-'0-9a-zÀ-ÿœēčŭ])", 'g');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like [see](https://regex101.com/r/lz875G/1) `[']?[a-zA-Z]+` to your RegEx where `[']` are the language special characters...

```
RegExp('\\b' + this.word + '[\']?[a-zA-Z]+\\b', 'g');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a shorter

```js
RegExp("(?<![-'\\p{L}])" + this.word + "(?![-'\\p{L}0-9])", 'gu');
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/Bn3woZ/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-'\p{L}0-9]           any character of: '-', ''', a Unicode letter, digits
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
foo                        a word
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [-'\p{L}0-9]            any character of: '-', ''', a Unicode letter, digits
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```